# How to force git to treat new file as new file, not as moved file?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm using Git Extensions. I have added a completely new (.csproj) file.
When I stage it, I see that it is treated as a moved (.csproj) file.

Obviously, I don't want this.

How do I *force* git to treat it as a new file?

Comment: Git detects the file as moved because you probably deleted a file whose content is similar enough to the content of the new file. Put the removal and the addition in separate commits and there is no moved file any more.

Comment: @axiac is right, but the even shorter answer is "you don't": Git isn't saying that the file *was* renamed, it's saying that if you want to do the same thing over again, it's less work to rename it (and then maybe change it a bit) than it is to remove the other file and create this one as a new file. Git's diffs aren't "what happened", they're instructions for a fast way to make it happen *again*.

Comment: @torek I agree. However, if Git detects a pair of removed+added files as a rename/move when it prepares the commit, it will also report the operations as a move in the diffs after the changes are committed. Apparently the OP doesn't want them to be reported as a rename/move.

Comment: @axiac: right, and splitting this into two commits means that Git won't be comparing the "before" directly to the "after" unless someone asks it to. So you'll normally see "before vs mid: delete file X" and "mid vs after: add new file Y". But it's also worth noting that when you compare "before" directly to "after", you can *tell* Git whether or not to detect renames. The default for `git diff` used to be "don't detect renames" but it changed as of Git 2.9 or so to "do detect renames".

Comment: I did not remove *anything*. I added a brand new file A that did not exist before. Git insists that I moved file B. I did not even touch file B with a 10 foot pole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As torek indicated, this is a bug in Git Extensions.
When I open a command prompt and check the output of `git status` the file shows as new.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force git to tread a file as new, as it automatically does. Git does not have an explicit move or copy functionality, as it versions content, not files and directories.

Renames and copies are detected ad-hoc when you do stuff like `git log` or `git diff` and in those commands you can tell Git not to do any detection, or only detect a file if it is similar by X percent.

If you want to prevent the rename detection to fire for this file in this commit, I fear you have to split your commit into two commits, one that deletes the old file and one that adds the new file.

Comment: I cannot, because I didn't delete anything. I added a brand new shiny file. Git insists that it is a move. It is not.

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: Ah, here we go. It says new file. Seems to be a bug in Git Extensions then...?

Comment: Maybe, I don't use Git Extensions

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug in Git Extensions. In general, if the path name *and* contents match in tree $old and tree $new, Git decrees those to be the same file, and having paired them up, never considers them again. (But see `--find-copies-harder` and various other options in various commands, which can modify this a bit.)